# identify the numeric values from xml page

Tags: xml, python-2.7

Arduino transmits this:

```
<stanza1>
<Humidity>
<sensore1>70.30</sensore1>
</Humidity>
<Temperature>
<sensore1>26.00</sensore1>
</Temperature>
</stanza1>
```

I would like to get the numeric values using this code:

```
from urllib import urlopen
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

doc = urlopen("http://192.168.0.116").read()

umi = ET.fromstring(doc).find('Humidity/sensore1')
temp = ET.fromstring(doc).find('Temperature/sensore1')
```

I can print `umi` or `temp`, but how can I get the numeric values from them? Are they objects?

Answer (score 0):

Get the inner string with `.text`, and then convert it into a number.

```
umi = float(ET.fromstring(doc).find('Humidity/sensore1').text)
```